# How to Remove elements from one JList and Add them to another JList?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

From `jlist1-->` I want to add the data to the `jlist2`, then I want to delete the data which is selected in `jlist1`.(For add part)

From `jlist2-->` I want to add the data to the `jlist1`, then I want to delete the data which is selected in `jlist1`.(For del part)

Comment: please provide SSCCE(Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)

Comment: I just can not understand the question. Can you put down your code snippet and be little more precise in asking the question?

Comment: https://hotfile.com/dl/165308628/bf580b4/Ekran_Alnts.PNG.html... I upload this. I did not put here the picture...

Comment: @FrknErgt, You shouldn't make us have to download something in order to help you..shadey stuff.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get selected element(s)
2. Remove selected element(s) from source list
3. Add selected element(s) (i.e. the element(s) previously removed) to the destination list

[Problem?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#mutable)